# How to make Windows 7 show all column headings the same for all folders?

Tags: windows-7

I have a few `.rmvb` files in a folder (these are the RealPlayer files but also playable by VLC) -- they are video files.  Only `.rmvb` files but nothing else are in this folder.

I don't know why the smart Windows 7 by default makes the folder show up with Album name, Artist name, Track #, Title, as if this is a folder for songs.  (were the programmers sleeping when they program Windows 7?)

Is there a way to just make all folders behave the same -- just to show  filename, size, type, and Date Modified, and that's it -- for all folders and nothing fancy?

Comment: It depends on the association, they might be categorized as audio files by the program with which you open them by default.

Answer (score 6):

In Explorer choose Tools - Folder Options. On the "View" tab in that dialog there is a button "Apply to All Folders" - that should to the trick and "copy" the layout of your active folder to all folders.

Comment: Perfect +1, try what guenter told :)

Comment: Maybe close...  this can "make folders of this type appear like this for other folders", but what about folders of other types?

Comment: You are right - "folders **of this type**". I don't know a solution for **all** folders. But is it a good idea to change the layout for really all folders? The Desktop is a folder, too, and there are some other folders with special functions

Comment: that's because those 4 column headings work well for me in most cases... if I do need to see different info I can customize that special folder type... but I think usually, probably just for mp3 for album info and photos for date taken.

Answer (score 2):

There are five different folder types; see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/

Comment: Can you summarize the linked page and post it here? Links can change or go down, which would invalidate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 press Organize -> Folder and search options.
Then (like in XP) you can switch to the "View" tab and press "Apply to All Folders".
That should to the trick and "copy" the layout of your active folder to ALL folders.

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate of the existing answer posted previously.